# How to change text in back button in a detailed view sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

What is the proper way to change the back button text?

```
    Ext.define('myapp.view.post.PostDetail', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.postdetailpage',
    xtype: 'postdetailpage',
    config: {
    navigationBar: {
        config: {
            //change the back button text?
            defaultBackButtonText: 'Go Back',
            useTitleForBackButtonText: false
        }
    },
    scrollable: 'vertical', 
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    tpl: ['{content}'],
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backbutton text is set in the navigation view before displaying the detailed view.

```
    Ext.define('mimo.view.PostPanel', {
        extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
```

`xtype: 'postPanel',

    requires: [
       'mimo.view.post.PostList'
    ],


    config: {
       title: 'Blog',
       iconCls: 'home',
    // set the back button text here
    defaultBackButtonText: 'Volver',


    items:[{
        title: 'Las entradas de blog',
        xtype: 'postlist'
    }]

   }
});

</pre>`

Answer (score 0):

You are extending Ext.Panel. Ext.Panel does not accept the navigationBar configuration, you probably want to use Ext.navigation.View. Then on that view you can pass the defaultBackButtonText property. Otherwise if you want to customize the button further, inside of navigationBar object you want to specify a button object with button properties.

Comment: If I use Ext.navigation.View then I get a second title bar that is blank. Is there a way from the view on the initialize event, when using Ext.Panel, to get the instance of the navigation/title bar and then change the button text?

Comment: yes, I found I can spceciy the back button in the previous view which is using Ext.navigation